# Matrix representation notation

Tags: matrices, notation

I realise this question would be more suitable for my lecturer but for certain reasons he cannot be contacted at the moment.

In his lecture notes he states the following:

**Definition:**

Let V be a finite dimensional space over a field k and let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be linear. The determinant of T is defined by: $\text{Det}(T)=\text{Det}([T]_B)$ where B is a basis of V.

**Lemma:**

The determinant of T is well-defined , that is it does not depend on the choice of basis B.

**Proof:**

Let B and E be two bases of V and denote by $I:V\rightarrow V$ the identity map, i.e. $Iv=v~~~\forall v\in V$. Then we have the following change of basis formula:

$[T]_B=[ITI]_B^B=[I]_B^E[TI]_E^B=[I]_B^E[T]_E^E[I]_E^B$

**My Problem:** No where in his notes has he used or defined what the notation $[I]_B^E$ means, I know the lower index means it is being represented in the B basis but I have no idea what the upper index means. Could someone else tell me ? and sorry for the round about way I have asked this question.. Cheers.

Comment: Since we are talking about basis transformation, if I were to guess, one of the letters is the original basis, and the other is the other basis. The change of basis is from B to E. On the left is a linear transformation T in the basis B, on the right is one in the basis E.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $T:V\to W$ is a linear transformation with  $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ a basis for $V$ and $E=\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ a basis for $W$, and $T(b_j)=\sum_ic_{ij}e_i$, for each $j$, then $$[T]_E^B=(c_{ij})_{i,j}.$$

In the special case $V=W$ and $T$ is the identity map, we have
$$
I(b_j)=b_j=\sum_i a_{ij}e_i.
$$
for some $a_{ij}$. The matrix $[I]_E^B=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$.